# how do I disable wlan0 hard block from rfkill

Tags: wifi, linux-device-driver

there are very similar questions to this one but all of them are solved by disabling some other wifi source by using modprobe and then reseting rfkill
in my case:

```
artixlinux:[rail]:/etc/modprobe.d$ rfkill list all
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: yes
```

and with nmcli:

```
wlan0: unavailable
        "Qualcomm Atheros AR9485"
        wifi (ath9k), 5A:9D:61:C0:BB:F0, sw disabled, hw, mtu 1500
```

I've already tried to modprobe ath9k but that does nothing

hardware:

```
[System]
OS:              Artix Linux 20220123 n/a
Arch:            x86_64
Kernel:          5.18.0-zen1-1-zen
Desktop:         KDE
Display Server:  x11

[CPU]
Vendor:          GenuineIntel
Model:           Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-3227U CPU @ 1.90GHz
Physical cores:  2
Logical cores:   4

[Memory]
RAM:             3.7 GB
Swap:            0.0 GB

[Graphics]
Vendor:          Intel
OpenGL Renderer: Mesa Intel(R) HD Graphics 4000 (IVB GT2)
OpenGL Version:  4.2 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 22.2.0-devel (git-3e679219a1)
OpenGL Core:     4.2 (Core Profile) Mesa 22.2.0-devel (git-3e679219a1)
OpenGL ES:       OpenGL ES 3.0 Mesa 22.2.0-devel (git-3e679219a1)
Vulkan:          Supported
```

Answer (score 1):

See https://askubuntu.com/a/98719

> "Hard blocked" cannot be changed by software, look for a wifi toggle on your keyboard or edges of the laptop; the device can also be hard blocked if disabled in the bios.

And:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/98702/how-to-unblock-something-listed-in-rfkill#comment618926_98719

> FYI hard block also happens when the wifi is disabled in the bios.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).